# Sumatra PDF: "restrict" mode without command-line param

Tags: command-line, sumatra-pdf

Sumatra PDF has "restrict" mode command line key `-restrict`. I want to use restrict mode without using cmd line. I run Sumatra PDF with 3rd party app, which cannot pass to Sumatra this cmd line key.

Is it possible to set "restrict" using "SumatraPDF-settings.txt" file?

Answer (score 0):

Found file for this usage. Copy http://sumatrapdf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/sumatrapdfrestrict.ini into the same folder as sumatraPDF.exe.